# How do I use bitwise operators with an str object in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, bitwise-operators, crc

I am trying replicate a CRC algorithm that uses a byte array in python 2.7. I noticed that when trying a bitwise operator, such as n >> 4, the program launches an exception saying "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'str' and 'int'", with n being a str object.

Which can I do so I can use the bitwise operator with an str object.

In my code n would have been initialized as being one of the chars that was initialized by the code,

bufferStr = ''.join(chr(x) for x in [0xE3, 0x01, 0x63, 0x03, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x00, 0x00])

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for the inverse operation of

```
bufferStr = ''.join(chr(x) for x in [0xE3, ....])
```

i suggest this:

```
ints = [ord(char) for char in 'hello world']
print(ints) # -> [104, 101, 108,...]
```